# How can I set a background overlay and button on a div when I hover?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, overlay

I'm trying to show a link that appears when I hover over the image. The goal is to fade the image and bring out the link with its background. I tried to do this but I'm doing something wrong. The background of the div comes out of the container. Also I don't know if the opacity method is the right one for hiding and showing.

Also I can't center the link in the image vertically or horizontally

Sorry, I'm new and just don't know how to fix. Someone show me the right way and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I appreciate any response. Thank you.

```css
.container_left {
    width: 20%;
}

.boxItems_first {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.boxItems_first a {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.boxItems_first:hover a {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 60%;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.boxItems_first:hover img {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_left">
  <div class="boxItems_first">
     <a href="https://mywebsite.com/shop/product" target="_blank">Product Page</a>
     
     <img width="auto" height="200" src="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/e5/d3/vertical_animation_fantasy_art-1693403.jpg!d" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy">
     
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Your image is covering the link. You would need to hide the link over the image. In other words, reverse the order of how you are doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you intend to reverse the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not too far off. The main thing you're missing is `position:relative` on the container, otherwise your `position:absolute` elements will be positioned based on the entire viewport.

You will also want to make sure your `transition` rules are not just applied on hover - the fade in/out looks quite janky otherwise. As a general rule, put your styles in the base class and only apply *changes* on hover.

Definitely more than one way to solve this problem but the approach of using `position:absolute` on the link element and transitioning the opacity on hover is fine. You just need to make the link 100% height and width and then use flex to align its children. Put a `<span>` around the link text so you can style that for the black background if you want it.

I've made some assumptions based on your post but this snippet should get you started:

```css
.container_left {
  width: 20%;
}

.boxItems_first {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.boxItems_first img {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.boxItems_first a {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  color: white;
}

.boxItems_first a span {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.boxItems_first:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
}

.boxItems_first:hover img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_left">
  <div class="boxItems_first">
    <a href="https://mywebsite.com/shop/product" target="_blank"><span>Product Page</span></a>
    <img width="auto" height="200" src="https://placedog.net/600" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" loading="lazy">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I was trying to do. However, I will modify the span a bit to make only the background of the link clickable and not the whole image.